# Javascript + MVC + UI

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm looking for fresh ways of programming in javascript. My goal is to create javascript application like GMail. I tried GWT but it seams so complicated and the code isn't stylish.

I found MVC patteren to be a good way of programming. I always have problems organizing the code in javascript. When I use CakePHP or RoR, everything is simpel :).

I'm looking for a javascript framework that would support MVC way of programming and would have good widgets like Adobe Spry Framework. What frameworks should I use? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

A List Apart has [an article about JavaScript MVC](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/). I don't think you should necessarily use a framework, unless you're already familiar with one.

That article also points out to some MVC frameworks:

- [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/)
- [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/)
- [TrimJunction](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimJunction)

Comment: Way to go! Haven't finished eye-scraping the site yet.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at Cappuccino: http://cappuccino.org

Answer (score 2):

Check out AngularJS - http://angularjs.org

It will help you a lot with your app structure and strict separation between logic and view.

Full test environment (unit/e2e) and dependency injection included...